Extract a substring after a specific pattern in R
I have a list of strings
mylist <- c("0-X-global-X-all_chondroitine-and-heparan-sulfate_synthesis", "100-X-global-X-all_retinol_metabolism", "2-X-global-X-all_type-I-ifn-response",                      "312-X-global-X-thrombolysis-factor_production")

I need to remove the first part of the string, e.g. "0-X-global-X-", so the resulting list looks like this:
c("all_chondroitine-and-heparan-sulfate_synthesis", "all_retinol_metabolism", "all_type-I-ifn-response",                      "thrombolysis-factor_production")


sub("\\d+-X-global-X-", '', mylist)

If i understand correctly, this can be accomplished using str_remove in tidyverse and a quick regex pattern:
library(tidyverse)

mylist <- c("0-X-global-X-all_chondroitine-and-heparan-sulfate_synthesis", "100-X-global-X-all_retinol_metabolism", "2-X-global-X-all_type-I-ifn-response",                      "312-X-global-X-thrombolysis-factor_production")

cleaned_list <- mylist %>% str_remove("^[0-9]{1,}-X-global-X-")

# "all_chondroitine-and-heparan-sulfate_synthesis" "all_retinol_metabolism" "all_type-I-ifn-response" "thrombolysis-factor_production"   

Or use Edward's solution if you want to keep it vanilla.

Do you really need to load tidyverse for such a simple task?

No, hence why I upvoted your answer. But there is likely more to OP's script then what is shown in this post... and there is a good chance that tidyverse is already loaded. If that's the case, then it makes sense to be consistent and stick with tidyverse for the sake of readability and clarity.
